# Multiple setImplicitCollections using XStreamMarshaller

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-batch, xstream

I am trying XStreamMarshaller. But when I try to parse two xsd:complexType of xml file i am getting this error :

```
class[1]            : com.mc.batch.mapping.authorization.PIECES_JOINTES
converter-type[1]   : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.ReflectionConverter
```

Xml :

```
<DOCUMENT>

    <ARTICLES>
        <ARTICLE>
            <NUMERO_ARTICLE>1</NUMERO_ARTICLE>
        </ARTICLE>
        <ARTICLE>
            <NUMERO_ARTICLE>2</NUMERO_ARTICLE>
        </ARTICLE>
    </ARTICLES>

    <PIECES_JOINTES>
        <PIECES_JOINTE>
            <TYPE_DOCUMENT>PDF</TYPE_DOCUMENT>
        </PIECES_JOINTE>
        <PIECES_JOINTE>
            <TYPE_DOCUMENT>WORD</TYPE_DOCUMENT>
        </PIECES_JOINTE>
        <PIECES_JOINTE>
            <TYPE_DOCUMENT>XLS</TYPE_DOCUMENT>
        </PIECES_JOINTE>
    </PIECES_JOINTES>

</DOCUMENT>
```

code :

```
@Bean
MessageConverter messageConverter() {

    Map<String, Class<?>> aliases = new HashMap<>();

    XStreamMarshaller marshallerAuthorization = new XStreamMarshaller();
    aliases.put("DOCUMENT", DOCUMENT.class);
    marshallerAuthorization.setAliases(aliases);

    Map implicitArticle = Collections.singletonMap(ARTICLES.class, "ARTICLE");
    Map implicitPiece   = Collections.singletonMap(PIECES_JOINTES.class, "PIECES_JOINTE");

    marshallerAuthorization.setImplicitCollections(implicitPiece);
    marshallerAuthorization.setImplicitCollections(implicitArticle);

    MarshallingMessageConverter messageConverterAuthorization = new MarshallingMessageConverter(marshallerAuthorization);
    messageConverterAuthorization.setTargetType(MessageType.TEXT);
    return messageConverterAuthorization;
}
```

But how to use two `setImplicitCollections` for mapping `PIECES_JOINTES.class` and `ARTICLES.class`

How do I resolve this conflict ? Any help would be welcome. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how to use two setImplicitCollections for mapping PIECES_JOINTES.class and ARTICLES.class

You don't need to call `setImplicitCollections` twice, the value passed in the second call will override the first one. This method accepts a map, so you can write something like:

```
Map<Class<?>, String> implicitCollections = new HashMap<>();
implicitCollections.put(ARTICLES.class, "ARTICLE");
implicitCollections.put(PIECES_JOINTES.class, "PIECES_JOINTE");

marshallerAuthorization.setImplicitCollections(implicitCollections);
```

Instead of:

```
Map implicitArticle = Collections.singletonMap(ARTICLES.class, "ARTICLE");
Map implicitPiece   = Collections.singletonMap(PIECES_JOINTES.class, "PIECES_JOINTE");

marshallerAuthorization.setImplicitCollections(implicitPiece);
marshallerAuthorization.setImplicitCollections(implicitArticle);
```